# WSClient won't see my WSDL file

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, wso2, wsh

Whilst attempting to follow the demos of the wso2 wsf for PHP framework, I don't seem to be able to run several of the example scripts, even though I've compiled and installed the wso2/wsf .so files and everything.

Specifically, whilst trying to run the sample script for WSDL I get the error:

```
Warning: WSClient::getProxy(wsf_wsdl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vagrant/public/test.php on line 8
```

Whilst running this code:

```
try {

    $client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"http://localhost:8888/samples/wsdl_mode/sample_wsdl_11.wsdl",
                                 ));

    $proxy = $client->getProxy();

    $return_val =  $proxy->QueryPurchaseOrder(array("productName"=> "Testing",
                                             "quantity" => 234,
                                             "date" => "2003-12-34",
                                             "orderNo" => 345));

    printf("<strong>Shipping address </strong><br/>");
    printf("Name : %s <br/>", $return_val["shipTo"]["name"]);
    printf("Street : %s <br/>", $return_val["shipTo"]["street"]);
    printf("City : %s <br/>", $return_val["shipTo"]["city"]);
    printf("State : %s <br/>", $return_val["shipTo"]["state"]);
    printf("Zip : %s <br/>", $return_val["shipTo"]["zip"]);

    printf("<br/><strong>Billing address </strong><br/>");
    printf("Name : %s <br/>", $return_val["billTo"]["name"]);
    printf("Street : %s <br/>", $return_val["billTo"]["street"]);
    printf("City : %s <br/>", $return_val["billTo"]["city"]);
    printf("State : %s <br/>", $return_val["billTo"]["state"]);
    printf("Zip : %s <br/>", $return_val["billTo"]["zip"]);

    printf("<br/><strong>Product info </strong><br/>");
    printf("Product ID : %s <br/>", $return_val["product"]["productId"]);
    printf("ShippingDate : %s <br/>", $return_val["product"]["shippingDate"]);
    printf("Status : %s <br/>", $return_val["product"]["status"]);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    printf("Message = %s\n",$e->getMessage());
}
```

The file definitely exists; when I run it in the browser I get the .wsdl file itself, however WSClient doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't include the WSO2 scripts in your `php.ini` file. Scripts should be in packeage distributed with the extension (there should be `scripts` directory). Save that directory in place that makes sense in your case (somewhere in your system, or somewhere in your project, it's up to you), and then put path to that directory in your `php.ini` file, like that:

```
include_path = "/path/to/wso2/scripts"
```

Eventually you could just put the wso2 scripts directory inside your php include directory. In any case you should restart apache service, for example:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And it should work.